# About selecting a MFC CListCtrl item

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, clistctrl

What I'm trying to do is select an item in a CListCtrl and make the selected item visible (scroll down). What is the best way to do this?

I have tried `myListCtrl.SetItemState(idx, LVIS_SELECTED, LVIS_SELECTED)` to select the item but I have to manually scroll down the ListCtrl to make it visible. There exists the function `CListCtrl::GetTopIndex` but I didn't find the counterpart `SetTopIndex`.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try with `EnsureVisible()`
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tbtcxzsf%28VS.80%29.aspx